# rails newbie: upon resource creation, render :location returns localhost:3000/users.id instead of localhost:3000/users/id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http-headers

I created a User resource via curl POST and I am trying to generate a respond with a http Location header.  Here is my routes.rb

```
resources: :users, only [:index, :create, :show] 
# get 'users/:id', :to => 'users#view' # removed based on a suggestion
post 'users', :to => 'users#create', :as => 'user'
```

In the users_controller (i skipped the exception handling code to simplify the code

```
def create
  user = User.create(name: params[:name])
  render :json => JSON.pretty_generate(user.as_json), :status => 200, content_type: 'application/json', location: user
end
```

The respond has a weird http location header.  User 10 is identified as users.10, not users/10

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: http://localhost:3000/users.10
```

How can I generate a location header like this?

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: http://localhost:3000/users/10
```

Thx!

Comment: user_path(user) didnt work?

Comment: Actually, you could replace `view` action with `show` and use a default resource's route.

Comment: Saravanan, user_path() produced the same result (users.10).  D-side, thx for the suggestion for routes.rb.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
def create
  user = User.create(name: params[:user])
  render :json => JSON.pretty_generate(user.as_json), :status => 200, content_type: 'application/json', location: url_for(user) # you did mistake here.
end
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: I ended up creating a url_for(user) in the controller. it seems to work but it does not seem right that I have to hardcode the url this way. def url_for(user) "users/" + user.id.to_s end

Comment: url_for() returns /users.10 instead of /users/10

Comment: Whats your route about user?

Comment: resources: :users, only [:index, :create, :show] 
post 'users', :to => 'users#create', :as => 'user'